# Matlab : datestr predefined date formats ISO8601

Tags: matlab, datetime, time, datetime-format, iso8601

When I look at [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)  Wikipedia's page, ISO8601 date should be "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" where [matlab's documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html?searchHighlight=yyyymmddTHHMMSS) predefined "yyyymmddTHHMMSS" which is not corresponding to ISO8601 :

- is there a mistake in matlab ?
- did the iso8601 recently changed ?

The solution I use is :

```
datestr(now,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') %instead of datestr(now,30)
```

But it does not look really "clean" for me ...

in addition, I don't understand about 'Z' parameter at the end. Is it supposed to appear if it is not UTC time ? why Matlab doesn't show it ? how to configure this ?

Thank you

Comment: In wikipedia they say that both are good, don't they? There are some gray boxes at the left with examples. e.g. `YYYY-DDD or YYYYDDD`.

Comment: "If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset"-Wikipedia

Comment: Hi @Ander Biguri : to my mind YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS is more readable than YYYYMMDDTHHMMSS that's why I would like to show it like this, thank you

Comment: I totally agree, its more readable. But you already have your solution! The answers of your questions are: No, there is no mistake in matlab, and the ISO didn't change, both are correct.

Comment: Isn't the correct format `datestr(now,'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss')`? The question has MM and mm the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
t = datetime('now', 'TimeZone', 'UTC')
datestr(t,'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss.FFFZ')
```

results in

```
'2017-10-29T10:30:55.488Z'
```

e.g. in Javascript import string (send over websocket) with

```
new Date('2017-10-29T10:30:55.488Z')
```